# Do muscles start growing evenly?

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain, muscle-mass, growth

I've searched information about this but I'm not able to find anything.

For example, when I started exercising, my pecs began growing near the armpits, and then the rest.

Did this part grow faster or it simply was noticeable while the rest of the muscle growth wasn't?

Comment: This isn't really answerable, as it will depend on the person, how they do the exercise, how their muscles react, etc. It's all very personal.

Answer (score 0):

As JohnP mentioned in the comment it will depend on the person and how they are training. But some muscles can grow quicker, because they react better to "natural" testosteron. I know of a few friends of mine who use anabolic steroids, and their traps and back muscles started to grow much fatser, because those muscles react good to testosteron.
For someone who trains natural, the difference will be probably negligible because of the amount of testosteron as long as the excercises are balanced.

Comment: But I've always heard that some muscles don't grow much, like the calves.

Comment: Most of the times those are myths created by people who dont train properly. genetics is a big part in growing the muscle, but if you have no real illness which limits growth your calves will grow, if you train them properly.

Comment: I've often said that my calves refuse to grow, but it's just a long-running joke. Fact is, I don't spend that much time on my calves, the same way I do with the other muscle groups.